# Tag wikis and answers

Tags: discussion, answers, etiquette, tag-wikis

Suppose there is an answer given by a user which seems like it would fit perfectly as a tag wiki entry (or part of one).

What should be the proper etiquette regarding copy&paste of the answer into the tag wiki?

Notifying by comment seems like a good idea, but what if the comment is not responded to, and some time have passed? A second comment? Just taking it off and leaving credit to the writer on the tag wiki?

Comment: I think suggestion via comment followed by a reasonable wait is sufficient; if no response, go ahead and copy and paste. You can always remove it if, at a later date, the author reappears and objects.

Comment: @Arturo: what about notifying the user?

Comment: Sure; say you put it as a comment suggesting you would like to do that. You wait an appropriate amount of time (whatever that may be); you get no response to the comment. You decide to go ahead and copy/paste it to the tag wiki description. Then you can post a follow-up comment saying you have gone ahead and done so, but if the author objects later you can take it down. Seems reasonable and corteous to me.

Comment: While I agree with Arturo that notifying the author is the courteous thing to do, by design of this website it *should* not be necessary. All content posted to the SE sites are released by the authors under a CC license, so *technically* you could just copy it over (with proper attribution etc.)

Comment: @Willie, Arturo: Thanks, actually last night I started copying into the tag wiki and then realized it does not fit as well I thought. I gave it the night and decided it is indeed unfitting, but I will "salvage" some parts of the answer into a tag wiki soon (with credits, of course).